# How to do auth without session but token in AJAX

Tags: session, redis, authentication

Since I want to auth the user in serval backends.

Such as nodejs, PHP, Erlang. How to simplify the auth system?

Can I save the auth data in redis or Mysql used by all backends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the token in mysql or redis if you don't want to use the standard session. As long as your ajax call sends the correct token or cookie to the server and this is compared adequately you will have no problem regardless of the language platform, whether singly used or combined.